# Paypal credit card REST api error

Tags: paypal

When i enable  credit card in my Paypal account it says:

Note: Direct credit card processing is not available for you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing for your country but your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing.

Comment: Direct credit card processing with REST is only available in the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

Direct credit card payment and related features are restricted in some countries. Please consult this link/guide where it explains a little bit more on that:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/#direct-credit-card-payments

As documented ".. accepting REST API direct credit card payments is supported only for existing Pro UK merchant accounts at this time".
Thanks,
Andrea