# How to enable pay with credit card without login in Paypal

Tags: php, rest, paypal, credit-card, recurring-billing

I have setup recurring billing with Paypal REST API, and the merchant account is set in Singapore, but i don't see an "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" option in the popup checkout page.
I have seen the answer in this thread: [Paypal credit card REST api error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955699/paypal-credit-card-rest-api-error) mention that it's only available for Pro UK merchant account.
So anyone can suggest me any ideas i can deal with this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like this is something that should be asked in a paypal support system

Comment: This question should be in proper support channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the buyer receives that error is because of it a guest checkout. Guest Checkout is not a 100% that is offered to your with your current account. Guess Checkout provide the buyer to pay with credit card but it is not a 100% success due to few factors that will reject the transaction such as:
1. If the buyer uses a credit card that already attached to a PayPal account.
2. If the buyer uses an email that is already attached to a PayPal account.
3. If the buyer already attempts multiple time on the same credit card and they received a decline or incorrect information was entered. Then, the credit card will be blocked or put under risk from our end.

These are the reason of the error that your buyer is seeing. To resolve this, they would need to have/create a PayPal account or use a different credit card to make the purchase. Some other merchant they might have a Pro account which only available for US, Canada, New Zealand and Australia. You may refer to the link here. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-gateway/?mark=payflow%20country
They have to use a direct credit card integration.

thank you.